# Get the value of the Selected option with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-select

How do I get the selected value from a dropdown list using JavaScript?

I tried the Method blow:

```
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="naan" name="naan">
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Choose Naan</option>
                            <option value="No Naan" style="font-size: 14px">No Naan</option>
                            <option value="Naan"  style="font-size: 14px">Naan</option>
                            <option value="Garlic Naan" class="red">Garlic Naan +$1.00</option>
                            <option value="Roti"  style="font-size: 14px">Roti</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                   var e = document.getElementById("naan");
                   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                   console.log('You selected: ', strUser);
```

It only selects the first option when I click the select box to select option. It returns "Choose Naan". If I remove first option then it returns "No Naan" instead of the value I select.

Comment: is that javascript code actually in a function that is called when the user makes a selection? as is, the code will run exactly once before you even get to select anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `strUser` appears to be being called directly from the page itself; as such, it only gets set when the page is rendered (and the user has yet to make their choice). What you want to do is run this block of code inside of a function that gets called when the value changes.

For example, you could add this in a function for [`e.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange):

```js
var e = document.getElementById("naan");
e.onchange = function() {
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; console.log('You selected: ', strUser);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="naan" name="naan">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Choose Naan</option>
    <option value="No Naan" style="font-size: 14px">No Naan</option>
    <option value="Naan" style="font-size: 14px">Naan</option>
    <option value="Garlic Naan" class="red">Garlic Naan +$1.00</option>
    <option value="Roti" style="font-size: 14px">Roti</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add an event listener and check the target node value to get the value of input...

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="naan" name="naan">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">
      Choose Naan
    </option>
    <option value="No Naan" style="font-size: 14px">No Naan</option>
    <option value="Naan" style="font-size: 14px">Naan</option>
    <option value="Garlic Naan" class="red">Garlic Naan +$1.00</option>
    <option value="Roti" style="font-size: 14px">Roti</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
  var e = document.getElementById("naan");

  //   Add add an EventListener and check the value in the target node...
  e.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the value of the selected option via the `change` event. In the example below, this is done by adding  `onchange="getSelectedValue(event)"` to the `select` element.

```js
function getSelectedValue(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="naan" name="naan" onchange="getSelectedValue(event)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Choose Naan</option>
    <option value="No Naan" style="font-size: 14px">No Naan</option>
    <option value="Naan" style="font-size: 14px">Naan</option>
    <option value="Garlic Naan" class="red">Garlic Naan +$1.00</option>
    <option value="Roti" style="font-size: 14px">Roti</option>
  </select>
</div>
```